# Keep my code DRY for `$onInit` and `$onChanges` methods

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, dry, angularjs-components

I have a piece of code that is repeated in almost all of my components:

```
import {deviceCommands} from "../../../core/data/Commands";


let _generalProperties = {
    'deviceName': deviceCommands.NAME.key,
    'deviceModel': deviceCommands.MODEL.key
};

export default class GeneralDeviceSettingsCtrl {
    constructor($scope) {
        let $ctrl = this;
        $ctrl.$onChanges = function (changes) {
            for(let prop in _generalProperties) {
                $ctrl[prop] = $ctrl.test.vm.data[_generalProperties[prop]];
            }
        };

        $ctrl.$onInit = function () {
            for(let prop in _generalProperties) {
                $scope.$watch(() => $ctrl.test.vm.data[_generalProperties[prop]],
                    (newValue, oldValue) => {
                        if (newValue !== oldValue) {
                            $ctrl[prop] = $ctrl.test.vm.data[_generalProperties[prop]];
                        }
                    });
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The only thing that is different is the `_generalProperties` variable, which is specific to my view.

How can I do to keep it DRY?
Make a base class? use decorators?

Comment: extending a base class is a simple and obvious pattern for this.  in many of my own projects, certain classes of components end up being handled this way.

Comment: Why do you attach methods to the object in the constructor, instead of defining the methods in the class?

Comment: You're asking about *_generalProperties*? No particular reason, I want my class to be as short s possible and keep the content to user interaction with the view

Comment: No I mean you do `$ctrl.$onInit = ...` inside the constructor. You could define the class's methods outside the constructor and just in the class.

Comment: Is it matter? I mean is there a difference?

Comment: Not really, it just seems cleaner to define them outside the constructor. Plus then the methods go on the prototype and are only created once, but I assume you're not creating this controller that many times anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is plenty of different approaches to this but if you stick with classes and inheritance you can supply the `_generalProperties` to your parent constructor and reuse the whole implementation.

For example:

```
export class BaseSettingsComponent {
    constructor(properties){
        this._properties = properties;
    }

    $onInit(){ /* ... implement base component stuff*/ }
}
```

Then, on each of your pages that uses the same component logic you can extend the base class, provide the properties to the parent class and let the base class do the job.

```
import { BaseSettingsComponent } from '../common/base-settings-component.js';

let _generalProperties = {
    'deviceName': deviceCommands.NAME.key,
    'deviceModel': deviceCommands.MODEL.key
};

export class GeneralDeviceSettingsCtrl extends BaseSettingsComponent {
    constructor(){
        super(_generalProperties);
    }

    $onInit(){ super.$onInit(); /* ... implement base component stuff*/ }
}
```

The one thing important to keep in mind when using this approach is that if you need to implement `$onInit` or `$onChanges` on the child classes you have to call the `super.$onInit()` otherwise you lose the parent behavior due to an override.

Finally, for an even cleaner code, you can also discard the declaration of `_generalProperties` supplying it directly into the `super` constructor.

```
import { BaseSettingsComponent } from '../common/base-settings-component.js';

export class GeneralDeviceSettingsCtrl extends BaseSettingsComponent {
    constructor(){
        super({
            'deviceName': deviceCommands.NAME.key,
            'deviceModel': deviceCommands.MODEL.key
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you remove the $scope? I need to $watch the object properties

Comment: Because it wasn't relevant to my code, but in your case, you can simply supply the scope through constructor, no problem with that, because the base controller, never gets registered on angularjs' module.